# Can a Spring MVC Application Alter SSL?

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, ssl

I'm disabling SSLv3 on some updated tomcat instances and all is well. `openssl` verifies SSLv3 is disabled... until I deploy the WAR file.

As soon as the WAR file is deployed and started, the tomcat instance begins answering Openssl with SSLv3 handshakes!

Undeploy and restart tomcat and it's back to having SSLv3 disabled.

What would be causing this issue? There is no embedded tomcat since it is not a Spring Boot application. `mvn dependency:list` also confirms no tomcat library.

**UPDATE**

Some of the ciphers I'm using in the server.xml are not available. I've added strong JCE jars which did make a few of the unavailable available.

Also, the web application does use 2 modules that implement 2 versions of BouncyCastle libs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out my problem. JAVA_HOME (jre/lib) did not have unlimited strength JCE jars. For whatever reason the application affected the security. Once I added the JCE jars and updated the security properties file I was back in business.